# set min and max value on editable column in xtraGridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, devexpress

Is it possible to set minimum and maximum possible value in editable column in xtraGridControl ? I want it to display 2 digits after comma in display mode :

12,24 $

and display 4 digits after comma while editing withous dollar :)

12,2400

and correct are only values > 0.

thanks for any help,
bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the column's editor to a `SpinEdit`.

You can then set the SpinEdit's `MinValue` and `MaxValue` properties, and its `DisplayFormat` and `EditFormat`.

Comment: But in edit mode I want to see: 4 digits after comma and be able to edit it not more then these 4 digits, in this case in spinEdit I can edit more than 4 digits after comma :/

Comment: So change the `EditFormat` or `EditMask`.

Comment: Go to the property grid and set the property.  You'll want something like `##.####` and `##.## $`.